# How I can refresh all dropdowns list on selection of value from drop-down

Tags: angular

- I've around 10 dropdowns in my application. all dropdowns gets values
  binded from 10 different arrays.
- When i select value in any of the dropdown then all 9 remaining
  dropdowns should not have the selected value.
- I can select any drop-down in any order. Only thing I want is to
  remove the selected item from the drop-down list.

e. g. I have 10 arrays with same values like [a, b, c, d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k] ..if I select **'a'** from **drop-down 3** then all remaining 9 drop-down **should not have 'a'**. If drop-down 10 selects 'b' then remaining dropdowns should not have 'b'.

I am new to Angular 5 and not able to implement the requirement above. please help me out.

Comment: can you show us what have you tried so far

Comment: Please generate a stackblitz links for the same, So we can see what all you have tried and help you in the correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the dropdowns are binded to the underlying arrays and you implement selected value change handlers on all 10 dropdowns then update the array's for the other 9 dropdowns to NOT include the selected value in the dropdown that had its value changed. Afterwards the databinding will update the other 9 dropdowns and not display / contain the selected value of the dropdown whos value got changed.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to resolve my issue with selected value change event